# How to run same day query for SQL Server

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating a package that will run every fifteen minutes and write a csv file into a shared folder. I am stuck on the query. I need the query to only go back to 12:00AM of the same day. Once it's the next day I need to have the query run only for that same day and not go back to the previous day.

I have tried this

```
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE() - 1))
```

but obviously that isn't producing the result I need.

Everything else on the query is fine and I am receiving the appropriate data I need.  However, I'm setting the dates at this time and that is not efficient.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm not a SQL Server expert and drudging through the TechNet documents has lots of information. I'm just having a difficult time connecting their information to my implementation.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Should use that as one of your tags as SQL syntax can differ between DBMS

Comment: Sorry Microsoft SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 + you can simply use:

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

To get the current date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get the current date (I'm sure there are many other methods as well)

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10)DATE, GETDATE(), 101))
```

as the -1 comment pointed out using varchars with dates is a bad idea (though everyone seems to do it all the time.  Another solution would be:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

though this won't work until a specific version of SQL server.

Yet another way to do it would be:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

which i believe would work on all sql server versions (though i find the hardest to understand)

The inner (convert varchar) gives you your date without time, then it is converted back into date format.

So for your query you could use

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME
SET @today = (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date >= @today
```

Comment: Updated, i find it the easiest solution to understand (while still working with all sql server versions that i'm aware of).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use date(now()) it will take 00:00:00 time by default.

Comment: What DBMS is this for?  now() and date() are not sql functions for MSSQL - though the OP did not specify DBMS so I was curious.

Comment: Oh.. I answered in postgreSQL

Comment: In the title i put Microsoft SQL.  Is that the information you're looking for?